# Imagemagick convert tif to rgba16 png

Tags: imagemagick, png, tiff, imagemagick-convert

So here is my source tif image:

```
$ identify -verbose source.tif
Image: 
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 512x512+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 7.11111x7.11111
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: Palette
  Base type: TrueColor
  Endianess: MSB
  Colorspace: RGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 1-bit
```

And I've tried:
convert source.tif output.png

And here are the results:

```
$ identify -verbose output.png 
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 512x512+0+0
  Resolution: 28.34x28.34
  Print size: 18.0663x18.0663
  Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  Type: Palette
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: RGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 1-bit
```

But I'm not seeing how to make the PNG be RGBA16.  Which as I understand means it needs a 16 bit depth, and an alpha channel.

Comment: Is that your entire command line? There seems to be no reason, then, to upgrade the destination channels, because the source fits exactly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Your input format 8-8-1 (which is unusual, by the way), seems to be converted to exactly the same format in PNG. The `convert` command did what you told it to, nothing mote. Perhaps you need to tell it you want a 16-bit output (which, if I understand correctly, needs *downsampling* to 4-4-4-4 channels).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, ImageMagick will use the *most economical* output format that is compatible with your specifications. So, if your input image doesn't have an alpha channel (i.e. transparency), your output image won't have transparency. If a 256-colour palette is adequate for the colours in your image, it will create a palettised output image. If an 8-bit output depth is adequate for your image, it will not bother creating a 16-bit output. And so on...

If you want to *force* ImageMagick to do something different, you have a number of options.

If you want to *force* true-colour, or a palettised (indexed) output file, you can do this:

```
convert input.png -type palette   output.png  # Force palettised (indexed) output
convert input.png -type truecolor output.png  # Force true colour output
```

If you want to *force* 8-bit or 16-bit, you can do this:

```
convert input.png -depth 8   output.png  # Force 8-bit output
convert input.png -depth 16  output.png  # Force 16-bit (per channel) output
```

If you want to *force* an alpha/transparency channel, you can do:

```
convert input.tif -type TrueColorAlpha output.png  # Force a true color output with transparency
```

And you can combine these too. If you want to see the *type* options, use this command:

```
identify -list type

Bilevel
ColorSeparation
ColorSeparationAlpha
ColorSeparationMatte
Grayscale
GrayscaleAlpha
GrayscaleMatte
Optimize
Palette
PaletteBilevelAlpha
PaletteBilevelMatte
PaletteAlpha
PaletteMatte
TrueColorAlpha
TrueColorMatte
TrueColor
```

Furthermore, specifically in the case of `PNG` files, you can also *force* the output by specifying the PNG type in capitals, followed by a colon in front of the output filename, thus:

```
convert input.tif PNG64:output.png     # Force 64-bit RGBA (3 channels @ 16-bits each, plus alpha)
convert input.tif PNG32:output.png     # Force 32-bit RGBA (3 channels @ 8-bits each, plus alpha)
convert input.tif PNG48:output.png     # Force 48-bit output (3 channels @ 16-bits each, no alpha)
convert input.tif PNG24:output.png     # Force 24-bit output (3 channels @ 8-bits each, no alpha)
```

So the short answer is

```
convert input.tif PNG64:output.png
```

or

```
convert input.tif -depth 16 -type TrueColorAlpha output.png
```

Beware though, ImageMagick will override the second version if no alpha channel is present in your input image, whereas it will not do that if you use `PNG64:`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  So why is it PNG64 if I want rgba16?

Comment: Because 4 channels @16-bits each = 64

Comment: For some reason I'm getting this error with the command: convert: unable to open image `PNG64:output.png':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2517.

Comment: What happens if you run `convert -size 100x100 xc:black a.png`

Comment: I also seem to be missing TrueColorAlpha when I run identify -list type

Comment: Ok, try `convert -size 100x100 xc:black PNG64:a.png`

Comment: I think you have an old version, try `identify -version`

Comment: On your last previous command I got: convert: no encode delegate for this image format `PNG64:~/a.png' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1189.

Comment: For version I got Version: ImageMagick 6.6.4-1 2010-12-17

Comment: That's ancient :-( You will definitely need to update.